# What should happen with unanswered questions when OP states they've found the solution?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

There are so many questions which have no answers but are solved. What should happen with them?

Why `nothing` is not good answer:

1. These questions are displayed in unanswered list.
2. These questions cannot be selected as duplicate.
3. Reading such question is a time spending until you realise that question was resolved. It's annoying.

Comment: Are you referring to where an answer is in the comments or where there is no answers at all (not even in the comments), but the questioner said that they have solved the issue, with no answer to their own question?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, and this and that.

Comment: @sectus: if you come across such questions, most likely it's better to flag or vote to close, especially if it's quite an old question.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, there is no such option in flag menu. But could be.

Comment: Closing as *too localized* could be the right thing to do.. oh wait, it doesn't exist anymore...

Comment: We burn the user!

Comment: Add a formal answer...

Comment: Wouldn't the first step be to leave a comment asking the OP to post their solution as a new answer? (assuming it's a relatively recent question)

Comment: @jcsanyi: I thought this was about when the OP says they found the answer but doesn't post that anywhere.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yes - I think the first step should be to encourage the OP to contribute an answer, regardless of whether they said what the answer was or just said it was solved.

Comment: @jcsanyi, there is another small problem that OP with rep less than 100 cannot answer himself in 8 hours.

Comment: Blackmail the OP: if he doesn't post the solution he have found, we will mass downvote ^^

Comment: @jcsanyi, and i think that ask to write answer similar to ask close NARQ question for example.

Answer (score 0):

Often the user mentions the solution or says "that worked!" in reply to a comment. In those cases I copy the comment to a new answer, marked community wiki.

Answer (score -1):

> What should happen with them?

- Suggest OP answers their own question
- Make an answer yourself with the solution

> These questions are displayed in unanswered list.

This is correct.
They are technically and literally unanswered - they "have no answer".

Comment: Three of your five suggested bullets are completely inappropriate actions to take.  Only the first and fourth are appropriate.

Comment: @Servy "completely inappropriate"? Care to expand as to why?

Comment: Questions should not be edited to say "resolved" ever.  If they're answered, the existence of the answer is already indicated from the question list.  Questions shouldn't be closed just because the OP has gotten a solution; none of the close reasons are applicable for such a situation.  If the question meets some other close reason then that's unrelated to whether the OP has found their solution.

Comment: @Servy Hmm, true. I think I answered this question too directly, in that at the moment leaving unanswered yet resolved questions hanging is bad, and my list is an improvement on their current state. i.e. OP states "annoying discovering is resolved after reading through the question + comments" so adding "resolved" at the top resolves that also. But you are right, thanks for the note - have removed the less savoury ones and left the most appropriate outcomes. Cheers